# Python runs smoothly until an error with scraping occurs tried to fix it using try and except but it doesn't seem to work

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

Python newbie here practicing my skills. I came across a roadbump and would be very happy to receive some help. What i'm trying to do is to get a list of links from a spreadsheet. From there, Python will get the data, extract a specific class and paste the data to ColB. Problem is, there are instances when the link is broken, hence there will be no data scraped. I used try and except to get around this but it seems like it's not working. What it seems to do is that when an error occurs, it just skips writing the data and proceeds to write the data on the wrong cell. here is my code:

```
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('Te....4e.json', scope)

gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)


#selects the spreadsheet
sh = gc.open_by_url('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u7....0')


worksheet = sh.worksheet('Keywords')
colvalue = "A"
rownumber = 2
updaterowvalue = 2

while rownumber <100:
    try:
        val = worksheet.acell(colvalue +str(rownumber)).value
        rownumber += 1
        url = val    
        #scrape elements
        response = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
        #print titles only
        h1 = soup.find("h1", class_= "sg-text--headline")    
        updatecolvalue = "B"    
                worksheet.update_acell(updatecolvalue +str(updaterowvalue), h1.get_text())
        updaterowvalue +=1
    except AttributeError:
        pass

print('DONE')
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the extra indentation on the line starting `worksheet.update_acell` is an error, since your code is invalid as given.

The problem is that when an exception occurs, `updaterowvalue +=1` is not executed, which causes the results to get out of sync with the URLs.

Fixing this is simple, just stop using `updaterowvalue` and just use `rownumber` in the `worksheet.update_acell()` call.  Since you want the result to be in the same row as the URL, `updaterowvalue` is unnecessary.

A more pythonic way of writing the loop would be:

```
for rownumber in range(2,100):
```

which allows you to eliminate the `rownumber += 1` line too.